# How to run a django test on an empty database outside of the test runner?

Tags: django, database, validation, testing

Our database accepts user-submitted load files, and for the time being, our admins are going to load the submitted files manually to resolve data issues.  There are 2 types of files.  For the second file to load successfully, the first file must load successfully.  Since we are going to handle this ourselves, I'm writing a data validation page that does a load of the first file in debug mode so that the user can resolve simple things like unique fields and controlled vocabulary issues.

But in order for me to test the second file, I need to temporarily load that first file.  I decided to do this by creating a TestCase class that is not a part of our unit test suite.  (Maybe there's a better way to do this than the strategy I've selected - so I'm open to suggestions.)

When I run the tests from the validation view in `views.py`, the tests work and the data does not persist in the database - however, I'm not getting a clean/empty test database to work from.  In order for this code to be guaranteed to work, I need to figure out how to create a fresh empty copy of a test database.  I found [this stack post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27810840/why-isnt-django-creating-blank-a-database-during-test), but I can't seem to get the suggestion in the answer to work. Even though I'm calling `setup_test_environment()`, the test database is still populated at the start (if it even is a test copy of the database).  Maybe I'm calling `setup_test_environment()` from the wrong place?

Here's what I have:

`views.py`

```
class DataValidationView(FormView):
    form_class = DataSubmissionValidationForm

    ...

    def form_valid(self, form):

        ...

        # Load the animal and sample data into a test database, so the data is available for the accucor file validation
        validation_test = self.ValidationTest()
        try:
            validation_test.validate_animal_sample_table(self.animal_sample_file.temporary_file_path())
        except Exception as e:
            valid = False

        # Load the accucor file into a temporary test database in debug mode
        for af in self.accucor_files:
            try:
                validation_test.validate_accucor(af.temporary_file_path())
            except Exception as e:
                valid = False

    ...

    class ValidationTest(TestCase):
        def __init__(self):
            setup_test_environment()
            self.setUpTestData()

        @classmethod
        def setUpTestData(cls):
            # Tried this in 2 places...
            setup_test_environment()
        
        def validate_animal_sample_table(self, animal_sample_file, table_headers):
            call_command("load_animals_and_samples",...)

        def validate_accucor(self, accucor_file):
            call_command("load_accucor_msruns",...)
```

Comment: Sorry it's a little unclear. This isn't actually a test? You want to save data from the first step to somewhere temporary for use in the second?

Comment: That's correct. I would like the data from the first file to load into a fresh/blank/empty copy of the database, the same way the tests (can) do, I believe. I'm not actually that familiar with the test database setup. I was hoping that would be pretty straightforward, I.e. very little code.

Comment: Using this process (if it's feasible) would mean that only one person could do this validation at a time, the test database would get overwritten on every first submission. Is that what you want? You would probably have to add some locking mechanism too

Comment: Actually, yeah. I want to do the test with the submitted files and then dump it. It's just a validation check. We plan to load the data properly in the real database later. The validation is just to reduce our manual efforts when we do properly load the data. It allows us to not have to have so much back and forth with the user to resolve things that they can do on their own.

Comment: We just don't want any student to be able to load data that hasn't been looked at by a curator, but at the same time, allow the to fix simple issues before it gets to us.

Comment: I would look into using [multiple databases](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/db/multi-db/), it's pretty much what the test database is anyway. Save all the user submitted data to a staging/approval database and then when it's approved migrate it to default

Comment: This is definitely not the final solution. It was my attempt at a quick validation. It works currently, but without the test database starting empty, it could have issues pretty quickly. Do you know how to initialize it?

Comment: Passing `keepdb=False` to [setup_databases](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/testing/advanced/#django.test.utils.setup_databases) should re-create the test DB without any data. Using the test db like this seems like it will run in to some issues though

Comment: Cool. I will try that tomorrow first thing. The code is otherwise ready for a PR aside from linking. I'll let you know how it goes.

Comment: OK, given my inference that the option name `keepdb` was regarding what to do with the test data after the test completed, I instead called `teardown_databases(keepdb=False)` before `setup_test_environment()` in the `setUpTestData` class method, and that appears to work the way I intend. So that's great. But now, what are your specific misgivings about using the test DB this way? I don't doubt there may be issues. I just don't have any idea what the risks may be - but I'm not a python/django expert, so that's not saying much.

Comment: Well, I take it back.  The first few times, the teardown seemed to work.  My latest tries haven't. I'll try your explicit suggestion.

Comment: Everything seems to work as expected, BTW. Merged the code yesterday. I'll keep an eye out for the issues you suggest may pop up.